# Unable to change IAM role for Oracle RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds

I have an oracle rds instance that I had an S3_integration iam role for, I removed it using terraform, but it was never deleted on the instance itself it seems.

Now I am unable to change, delete or add any s3_integration roles to the instance.

[image]

Attempting to use terraform or the UI to change the name, or delete it have been unsuccessful, has anyone had this happen? How can this be fixed? I cannot find any information about why the role is invalid, and attempting to upload a dump using rdsadmin_s3_tasks.upload_to_s3 command shows me this error "`[ERROR] The DB instance doesn't have credentials to access the specified Amazon S3 bucket. To grant access, add the S3_INTEGRATION role to the DB instance.`"

I've rebooted the database but it has no effect.

Comment: Are there any lifecycle policies or are you maybe ignoring IAM role changes in the Terraform code for the RDS? Can you add that to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by removing the iam role using the aws cli, the UI didn't have the role but it could be found by describing the aws instances.

It was then removed using:

```
 aws rds remove-role-from-db-instance \
--db-instance-identifier db_name \
--role-arn arn:aws:iam::xxxxxx:role/rds-s3-datadump-role \
--feature-name S3_INTEGRATION
```